# Reading a file into a dictionary in python, how do I make sure there are no duplicates?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, text-files

I am reading in a file and creating a dictionary of the first two items in each line, how would I make sure that none of the keys are the same so that I can close out the file if this happens? I have the code that makes the dictionary but I am unsure how to do this troubleshooting, any insight would be much appreciated!:
Here is my code for the dictionary:

```
my_dict = {}
info = open(data_file,"r")
for line in info:
    line = line.rstrip()
    items = line.split('\t')
    ID = items[0]
    Value = items[1]
    my_dict[ID] = Value
    return my_dict
```

Comment: Do you mean just checking `if ID in my_dict:`?

Comment: yeah, as it is entering the items into the dictionary I want it to stop if there is and repeating IDs

Comment: Just check `if ID in my_dict: raise SomeException` before the line `my_dict[ID] = Value`

Comment: awesome! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just like that:

```
my_dict = {}
with open(data_file,"r") as info:  # Closes upon finishing
    for line in info:
        items = line.rstrip().split('\t')
        ID = items[0]
        Value = items[1]
        if ID in my_dict:  # Exits the for loop if ID already exists
            break
        my_dict[ID] = Value

    return my_dict  # Returns the gathered data
```